# Pycharm application static path?

Tags: powershell, pycharm

Playing with Powershell, fuzzy finder and pycharm with JB Toolbox. My goal is to be in terminal press CTRL + P, pick a directory from fzf and open it in Pycharm.

added to path:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\231.8109.197\bin`

in this dir is a pycharm.exe of newest pycharm version (231.8109.197) -  it works like a charm BUT when new version comes out, I obviously have an issue with path.

```
$pycharm = {
    $path = Get-ChildItem -Path ~/Work,~/Github -Directory -Depth 0 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | fzf
    pycharm64.exe $path
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}

Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+p' -ScriptBlock $pycharm
```

is there a static path for pycharm I don't know about? Or do I have to go tru all the version, find the newest one and proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solved with

```
$pycharm = {
    $path = Get-ChildItem -Path ~/Work,~/Github -Directory -Depth 0 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | fzf
    $pycharm_path = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P"
    $pycharm_exe = Get-ChildItem -Path $pycharm_path -Filter "pycharm64.exe" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match '\\\d+\.\d+\.\d+\\bin' } |
        Sort-Object { [version]($_.DirectoryName -replace '.*\\(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\\bin', '$1') } -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName

    if ($pycharm_exe) {
        & $pycharm_exe $path
    } else {
        Write-Host "PyCharm executable not found. Please check the installation."
    }
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}

Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+p' -ScriptBlock $pycharm
```